# After disassociating user profile service application from web application, not able to edit user properties

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Initially we did not had user profile service application configured for the web application and we were able to update the user properties as shown in below image
 [image]

After configuring user profile service application and associating web application we were getting redirected to user profile to update the user information.
For some reason we dint wanted to use user profile for this web application and we created a new service application proxy group which does not include user profile service application and associated this group to our web application.
And now when we try to edit user profile we only get Default request property to update but not other properties, as shown in below image
[image]

Wanted to understand why is this behavior happening and how to configure so that we get option to update all the other properties of user(we don’t want to associate user profile service application)

Answer (score 0):

@mallialways  You can try following things.

1. Go in CA -> Application Management -> Manage service application -> User profile service application -> People - > Manage user properties

Edit one of the property, Lets say First name, Using the dropdown click on edit option.

On the EditProperty.aspx page, Please check two options,

- Edit Settings -> Check - Allow users to edit values for this property
- Display Settings -> Check - Show on the Edit Details page & Show in the profile properties section of the user's profile page

You wil have to **repeat** this step for every property which you want to edit.

I hope it helps :)